# SP2013 - Calculated column to check if column is blank, yes or no

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a calculated column that checks to see, if Send Form column is either Yes, No or Blank.

If yes then the date should be today's date, if No or blank then it should be "N/A".

The formula below always returns "N/A" regardless if Yes.

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Send Form]),IF([Send Form]="Yes",TODAY(),IF([Send Form]="No","N/a",)),"N/a")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse your arguments.

The if function takes 3 arguments (bool, trueval, falseval)

If isblank is true, then it cannot equal a value

It should be if not blank instead.

Encapsulate your isblank inside a not function

Not(isblank(...))